# How does giving Apple my CCV code confirm I am a parent of my child?

Tags: icloud

I am setting up iCloud account for my child (just created a family). After setting nickname and entering my child's data, I am prompted for CCV code for my card, and it says:

"confirm you are the parent or legal guardian of this child by entering the security code for the card, Visa (**** 1234)" - last 4 numbers are from my card.

I can't understand - how does it confirming I am a parent?! And why is this even needed?

Answer (score 4):

It confirms you are owner of the card - or at least have it in your hand.

Presumably, that is considered a minimum identity check, assuming the last names match. Sending in a photocopy birth certificate seems a bit 1980s these days ;)

The [CARD Act of 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_CARD_Act_of_2009) says that to have a credit card in one's name they must be 18 years old with a verifiable source of income or be 21 years of age.  Asking for the CCV of the card when setting up the child's account is just Apple's due diligence that the card associated with the parent's account is "in hand of an adult" and that the parent is aware the account is being created.

Comment: In addition, it puts a valid credit card on the account so Apple can charge for any purchases made by the child.

Comment: @fsb - the credit card was already lodged, according to the OP - they just wanted CCV confirmation; which is the usual way of confirming you at least have it in your hand.

Comment: Yes, the OP asked "And why is this even needed?" I was addressing that point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer already covered that.

Comment: I disagree as your answer didn't address that point; it addressed ownership of the card.  It might be implied in the answer which is why I didn't edit the answer to add that info.

Comment: @fsb - Then provide your own answer & let the membership decide, rather than go on about it in comments. The OP doesn't appear, imo, to be questioning the presence of the card, merely that confirmation of the CCV is 'proof' of parent status.